# Issue regarding paypal IPN in codeignitor

Tags: codeigniter, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am integrating PayPal payment gateway in my code ignitor website. and I am using this ref

https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter/

All things are successfully done but payments transaction data is not saved into the database.

I have set the IPN URL in the sandbox business account. And in the IPN history page, It showing IPN was sent successfully. but IPN data not received on my website.

I also test IPN using the IPN simulator. When I put my base URL like https://www.earlyyearz.com/ then IPN was sent successfully. but when I give the path of my IPN function

https://www.earlyyearz.com/payments/ipn then it was saying IPN not sent.

does anyone can help me to fix this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add logging to your IPN function so you can see what is happening when it receives the data.  If your IPN function does not respond with an HTTP 200-level status, PayPal will mark the IPN as not having been received.

IPN is an extremely old service that was not designed for modern web integrations.  If this is a new integration, first ask yourself why you are using IPN to begin with (you shouldn't need it for a normal [PayPal checkout with server API captures](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server))

But if you really do need asynchronous notifications (again, you shouldn't need them), use [webhooks instead of IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/).